# Guice Dynamic Binding, get Instance

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm new in Dependency Injection & Guice in Java. I have a problem with dynamic injecting suitable object.

For example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());

        StudentStore studentStore = injector.getInstance(StudentStore.class);
        RegisterService registerService = injector.getInstance(RegisterService.class);

        registerService.register("First User");
        registerService.register("Second User");

        //Now I would like to use OfflineRegisterService.class - is it good idea to do it here?
        registerService = injector.getInstance(OfflineRegisterService.class);

        registerService.register("Third User");
        registerService.register("Fourth User");

        System.out.println(studentStore.size());
    }
}
```

It works but is it the best idea to do it?

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(StudentStore.class).to(MemoryStudentStore.class);
        bind(RegisterService.class).to(OnlineRegisterService.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I find your example confusing. This looks like static code. I would use a property file (or similar) to create named bindings for user 1 through 4, then annotate the RegisterService with the properties you want to register and do it in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

As for Guice, your solution is fine. For code readability I would create a new local variable for the offline one. So you always know which one you're using:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());

        final StudentStore studentStore = injector.getInstance(StudentStore.class); // final prevents reassignment
        // do some stuff

        //Now I would like to use OfflineRegisterService.class - is it good idea to do it here?
        final offlineRegisterService = injector.getInstance(OfflineRegisterService.class); // final too

        offlineRegisterService.register("Third User");
        offlineRegisterService.register("Fourth User");

        System.out.println(studentStore.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. You said "fine". Could it be better?

Comment: For this static code you have, this is perfect. Some real-life scenario would be useful. E.g. you need different registers for test a prod? Do you want to switch between registers based on a config?

Comment: I would like to switch between register based on user decision. If he would like to register online(he will be registered online), if he would like to register offline(he can print form).  Should I make next interface and class which will mange this situation?